# Error in restore database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I use this query in SQL Server 2008 R2 to restore `DB1` database:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DB1] 
FROM DISK = N'D:\new.bak' 
WITH RESTRICTED_USER, FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10;
```

The following error is displayed:

> *Msg 3102, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   RESTORE cannot process database 'DB1' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.
>
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message seems pretty clear: you cannot be using the `DB1` database when trying to restore it - instead, use the `master` database!

So in SQL Server Management Studio, first **close** all windows that are open and using that database! Then run this:

```
USE master
GO

RESTORE DATABASE [DB1] 
FROM DISK = N'D:\new.bak' 
WITH RESTRICTED_USER, FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10;
```

Comment: can not use 'Use master' in SP. error display.

Comment: @AhmadKazemi: in what **database** does your stored procedure exist?

Comment: i want use this query in SP. Can I do it?

Comment: It depends on what database that stored procedure is created inside of. Obviously, you cannot have that stored procedure inside the database you're trying to restore ....